# Remainder operator in c89 and c99

Tags: c, c99, c89

**c99** standard says that result of modulo operation has same sign as first operand. So `-9 % 7 = -2` and `9 % -7 = 2`.

I read in one book that c89 standard depends on implementation. So `-9 % 7` could yield `-2` or `5`??? How remainder of `-9 / 7` could be `5`?

Comment: -2 X 7 + 5 = -9. I thik this is the logic

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider two numbers `a` and `b`.

The quotient `q=a/b` and remainder `r=a%b` satisfy the equation `a == q*b + r`.

An (hypothetical) implementation of C89 in which -9 % 7 produces 5 is an implementation in which -9 / 7 is computed as -2.

The mathematical (Euclidian) division constrains `r` to be positive and smaller than `b`. C99 constrains it to be of the same sign as `a` and strictly between `-b` and `b`.
It is all only a matter of convention.

Comment: If integer division does not truncate but "rounds down" (towards -infinity), then this is reasonable, isn't it?

Comment: @H2CO3 I work on a static analyzer in which sets of possible values can be summarized as congruence information (for instance: “in this program at this line it is known that all values of `x` are equal to 1 modulo 3”). The analyzer uses Euclidian division because it has the best algebraic properties, but I have grumbled against C99's (really, processors') easier-to-implement-but-less-algebraic choice more than once.

Comment: I see, but 1. I don't think it makes a lot of sense to complain about the standard, it was written so that it's easy to implement (how else would you explain all the undefined behaviors?) and 2. it seems logical to me to be permissive about this, I don't think forcing integer division to round towards 0 is a good idea.

Comment: @H2CO3 I think that your points 1. and 2. explain the choice in C89 (they were trying to make everyone happy). In C99, they must have looked and realized that **every** hardware implementation was doing truncation, so the standard might as well specify division this way. Division with truncation is easier to implement in hardware because the sign and absolute value of the result can be computed in parallel.

Comment: Yes, of course it's easier to implement and in fact I go fo it as well, but why not let others do differently?

Comment: @H2CO3 Because when trying to write a C program, it is a pain not to be able to assume that division works one way or the other. An even more extreme position would be “why specify division at all in the standard? Why not leave it as a compiler-specific extension that (in practice) all compilers would have?". The answer is that a language standard such as C is a compromise between allowing leeway in implementations and allowing programmers to program concisely and portably without having to detect the behavior of division at compile-time.

Comment: Alright, this is a perfectly valid reason - unfortunately, which, as you also said, C does not seem to originally have been designed in mind with.

Answer (score 6):

`%` operator is defined as:

```
a == (a / b * b) + a % b
```

so

```
a % b = a - (a / b * b)
```

**% as a remainder operator**

If `/` rounds towards `0` (like C99):

```
-9 % 7 == -2
```

you have `-9 / 7 == -1` so the `%` is `-2` because

```
-9 % 7 == -9 - (-9 / 7 * 7) + 9 == -9 + 7 == -2
```

**% as a modulo operator**

If `/` rounds towards minus infinity:

```
-9 % 7 == 5
```

you have `-9 / 7 == -2` so the `%` is `5`

```
-9 % 7 == -9 - (-9 / 7 * 7) + 9 == -9 + 14 == 5
```

Comment: *If / rounds towards minus infinity* That behaviour is prohibited by the standard from C99 onward, right?